# intercept clicks inside iframe with android WebView

Tags: android, iframe, webview, android-webview, iframe-app

Is that possible at all? The closest I have arrived was to intercept through onLoadResource.

I need something like the shouldOverrideUrlLoading where it intercepts the click.